# Calling MSSQL stored procedures from iReport

Tags: sql, sql-server, jasper-reports, ireport

I want to call an stored procedure in an MSSQL server from iReport.

Query:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
SET DATEFORMAT mdy 

Exec SP_SAMPLE '12-jan-2008', '12-jul-2011', 
"$P!{Param1}", 
"$P!{Param2}", 
1, 
"$P!{Param3}" 

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
Where, 
    Param1 = 'A436F3A9-6A8B-40C4-B38E-567B05522449',
        '4DD40BC2-3390-4B1B-8841-        483A8FDAB2FD',
        'B95E8F04-6EE7-4BC6-BDD0-F95C4AFDAC0B',
        'AE757961-0E25-41B8-A382-    7600DDA0ABC7',
        '90B9CC0C-6090-4CEF-8BC9-9C8EA3C0F63C',
        '1E191B19-13D0-4CE2-B1EC-    3CFF9316887F',
        'A9EE7AE9-435C-4164-96F5-3DB20A6321BE',
        'DCD6D045-8B42-4B83-8C97-21EE9DFF644C'
    Param2 = '4E6E8464-F08A-4BB8-950F-38908E4E7B30',
        '76EBA40E-F898-4541-9208-8A6B3A35E082',
        '7C64DA92-C168-4A74-8955-F1974258AD12',
        '2E6DDC25-E037-4842-9E7F-2B9586561744'
    Param3 = 3EC43FB7-F258-4441-8188-A55E7BD40ADE
```

Note that stored procedures `param1`, `param2`, `param3` are of text datatype in sqlserver. Whereas in iReport I made them a collection.

Could any one tell me how can I generate the above query in iReport with the double quotes?

Also, Is there any way to display the query with filled parameter values when running iReport?

Answer (score 0):

Jasper Reports operates with two types of parameters: $P{name_parameter} and $P!{name_parameter}.
You using $P! parameter in query that give you full control on building query.

Example:

```
<parameter name="strParam1" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="strParam2" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="strParam3" class="java.lang.String"/>
<queryString><![CDATA[SELECT atr1 FROM mytable WHERE stratr1=$P{strParam1} AND stratr2=$P!{strParam2} AND stratr3=$P!{strParam3}]]></queryString>
```

If:

```
strParam1 =  string1 // (without quotes)
strParam2 = 'string2' // param (with quotes)
strParam3 =  string3 // (without quotes)
```

the result query will be:

```
SELECT atr1 FROM mytable WHERE stratr1='string1' AND stratr2='string2' AND stratr3=string3
```

> Also, Is there any way to display the query with filled parameter
>   values when running iReport?

In IReport 4.1 you can view resulting query in output console (iReport output window).

You can set log4j.properties to see result query for custom java application.

Comment: Could you please tell me how can i get the resultant query like following, I will pass parameter _['abc','def','ghi']_ through collection parameter? _Select "'abc','def','ghi'"_

Comment: Also, could you please explain me, how to display the query with filled parameter values when running using standalone iReport application?

Comment: @Srinivasan__ Your expression will be: <![CDATA[SELECT "$P!{strParam}" ...]]></queryString>

Comment: Srinivasan__ In IReport 4.1 you can view resulting query in output console (iReport output window)

Comment: I cant find resultant query filled with parameter values in iReport output window. Also, the _SELECT "$P!{strParam}"_ is not working, it displays an sqlexception stating, maximum length of string is 128. Could you plz help me out?

Comment: @Srinivasan__ What version are you using?